# is there an App that can extracts parts of a mp3 file without re-encoding the file?

Tags: macos, mp3

I have a big (one hour) mp3 file and want to make one mp3 for song or section of the big mp3, without re-encoding.

Would be great to have a  UI that  permits the selection of the sections that I want to save as individual mp3s.

I want to know if is at all possible to do it without re-encoding the file section again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like Rogue Ameoba's [Fission](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/fission/) should do what you want:

> With Fission's streamlined audio editing, you can quickly copy, paste and trim audio, as well as split files. Fission also works with compressed MP3 and AAC formats to edit without the quality loss caused by other editors. Get perfect quality audio when editing natively in the MP3, AAC, Apple Lossless, AIFF and WAV formats.

Comment: this application looks very good but a little expensive for using only to split mp3s

Comment: They also have [nice page](https://rogueamoeba.com/support/knowledgebase/?showArticle=MiscPlatformCorollaries) listing possible alternatives for Windows users.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to go with [Magic Cutter](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/magic-cutter/id431721059?mt=12) because was on the AppStore and does the split very easy.

I would like to have used the [Mp3splt Project](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php) but was lazy to see how I could install it on my Mac.